# Some Simple Questions for knowledge?

Tags: operating-system

Before Some days my friend ask me some simple questions, but I have no answer.
Please tell me about these questions.

1. How many computer programming languages are used all in the world ?
2. I want to create a language like 'java or c#'. What is the procedure for creating a language and how it will create?
3. Which language is used for manipulate Window operating system?
4. What is the procedure of create Operating System like Windows/Linux/Mac and in which language it should create?
5. What is the procedure of create open source framework project in javascript and php?

Comment: 6. What is the meaning of life?

Comment: Life is a way in dark where you can't see anything and don't know what you will do in future. Its a great truth of life.

So always be happy
:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many computer programming languages are used all in the world ?

Wikipedia [lists a lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) of them!

> I want to create a language like 'java or c#'. What is the procedure for creating a language and how it will create?

If you need an answer to this question probably you won't be able to create one, I guess (definitely I wouldn't be able to).
Anyway, if you want to go that way and create a very very simple language you should start by building a parser that takes the commands you wrote and interprets them to do something, checks for syntax errors etc. That already will take a big effort.

> Which language is used for manipulate Window operating system?

You can use several: C++, C#, Visual Basic, etc etc etc
Microsoft provides several [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx) ([Application Programming Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)s) to "manipulate" Windows

> What is the procedure of create Operating System like Windows/Linux/Mac and in which language it should create?

As for #2. If you're starting programming you probably better focus on a simple project. Creating an OS is a **huge** effort and it requires profound knowledge of the computer architecture. You would probably create it using C++ and/or Assembly I guess. (as above, I wouldn't be able to create a programming language, an OS is completely out of question)

> What is the procedure of create open source framework project in javascript and php?

This question does not make too much sense to me. You create your project and then release it to the public under an opensource licence, e.g. [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).